# Comparando si 2 listas son idénticas usando solamente Base R sin tener en cuenta el orden de sus elementos

Tags: r

Quiero comparar si 2 listas son idénticas usando solamente Base R sin tener en cuenta el orden de sus elementos.

Encontré una solución.

Es mi respuesta correcta?

Muchas gracias!

```
subject_list <- list("x", "y")
candidates_list <- list("y", "x")

subject_vector <- unlist(subject_list)
candidates_vector <- unlist(candidates_list)

subject_vector <- sort(subject_vector)
candidates_vector <- sort(candidates_vector)

all.equal(subject_vector, candidates_vector, tolerance = 0)
```

Comment: Es interesante lo que planteas, tengo algunas observaciones y me gustaría responderte, pero lo que pides es una opinión y eso es motivo de cierre, por lo que me tome la libertad de replantear tu pregunta de forma más concreta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/570659/31764

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Genial tu respuesta! Te agradezco mucho que hayas publicado otra pregunta.