# ¿Cómo comparar dos listas desordenadas?

Tags: r

Quiero saber si dos listas son idénticas, es decir que tienen los mismos elementos y el mismo número de los mismos, básicamente deberían verificarse estos supuestos:

```
list(a="x", "y") == list("y", "x")      # TRUE 
list("x", "y") == list("x", "y", "y")   # FALSE
```

Además

- Todos los elementos son atómicos (no hay otras listas u objetos más complejos)
- Los atributos no son importante, solo los valores de cada elemento

¿Qué opciones tengo para hacer esta comparación ya que no hay ninguna función básica para resolver esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en sí, se puede reducir a transformar la lista en vectores y resolver la comparación entre estos. Hay varias alternativas para resolverlo según los supuestos de la pregunta:

```
identical_list_1 <- function(l1, l2) {
  v1 <- unlist(l1, use.names=FALSE)
  v2 <- unlist(l2, use.names=FALSE)
  isTRUE(all.equal(sort(v1), sort(v2)))
}

identical_list_2 <- function(l1, l2) {
  v1 <- unlist(l1, use.names=FALSE)
  v2 <- unlist(l2, use.names=FALSE)
  identical(sort(v1), sort(v2))
}

identical_list_3 <- function(l1, l2) {
  v1 <- unlist(l1)
  v2 <- unlist(l2)
  Reduce(identical, Map(table, list(v1, v2))) 
}
```

Comentarios:

- Con un poco de ajustes, todas estas funciones se plantearon en [Check whether two vectors contain the same (unordered) elements in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912800/check-whether-two-vectors-contain-the-same-unordered-elements-in-r)
- Tanto `all.equal()` como `identical()` consideran los atributos (nombres de los elementos), por lo que debemos transformar las listas en vectores sin considerar estos: `unlist(l1, use.names=FALSE)`, sino, el primer ejemplo de la pregunta fallaría.
- Si usamos `all.equal()` pero queremos retornar un valor lógico, hay que envolver la función con `isTRUE()`
- Las dos primeras funciones usan `sort()` algo que puede ser bastante costoso, sin embargo los benchmarks las dan como ganadoras
- La tercer función, genera 2 tablas de frecuencias para cada vector y los compara luego mediante `identical`, la idea era evitar el `sort` aunque seguramente `table` ya lo debe estar usando internamente.

---

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(2022)
l1 <- as.list(sample(1:10000))
l2 <- as.list(sample(2:10001))

microbenchmark(identical_list_1(l1, l2),
               identical_list_2(l1, l2),
               identical_list_3(l1, l2), times = 10L)

Unit: microseconds
                     expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 identical_list_1(l1, l2)   696.7   851.0  1456.18   987.4  1331.4  5541.1    10
 identical_list_2(l1, l2)   384.0   425.4   494.41   475.7   557.4   701.0    10
 identical_list_3(l1, l2) 12396.0 12488.1 13091.43 12830.7 13545.5 14380.5    10
```

Comment: Fantástica respuesta! Muchas enseñanzas! Eres un gran profesor!

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor añadir una explicación de la tercera función? Las dos primeras están muy bien explicadas. ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: @Beginner, agregue un comentario con respecto a la función, que no te confunda el uso de `Map()` y `Reduce()` , conceptualmente se está haciendo algo así `identical_list_3 <- function(l1, l2) {t1 <- table(unlist(l1));t2 <- table(unlist(l2));identical(t1, t2)}`

Comment: Gracias Patricio! Excelente explicación, como siempre!